# Eclipse IDE Slow Download - Marketplace/Updates

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I am trying to download tools for Java dynamic web development and spring boot release 4 on Eclipse Photon. I do not see option for dyamic web project with original Photon download. The download speed is extremely slow and it appears stuck at 49%. Is this normal and is there a way to improve the speed? Other posts have not helped that I read. Thank you.

Comment: Check your internet connection.

Comment: connection is fine

Comment: The option would have been the IDE for Java EE Developers.

Comment: I know but I should be able to add the web developer downloads to Photon no?

Comment: even spring boot download goes on forever

Comment: The download is not done directly from the Eclipse Marketplace but from the update site given by the Marketplace entry. Do you want to install or to update something? Please add the links of the Marketplace entries that you want to install or update to your question. If you do _Help > Check for Updates_ or install something from Marketplace, all enabled update sites (_Window > Preferences: Install/Update > Available Software Sites_) are used. Removing or disabling the update sites that are not required anymore might solve your issue.

Comment: thanks @howlger...makes more sense now..i will give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing *may* be tied to the active provider in Eclipse's [Network Connections](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-net-preferences.htm) settings:

- **Direct** - "Choosing the Direct provider causes all the connections to be opened without the use of a proxy server."
- **Manual** - "Selecting Manual causes settings defined in Eclipse to be used."
- **Native** - "On some platforms there is also a Native provider available, selecting this one causes settings that were discovered in the OS to be used."

**Note:** After changing and applying the setting, restart Eclipse.

I have personally used Direct for a home connection (Eclipse 2018-12 / 4.10.0) and Native for an enterprise system with proxies (Eclipse Neon.2 / 4.6.2) to resolve sluggish Marketplace behavior.

For the uninitiated, these settings are found:

1. In the Eclipse MenuBar (top), select Window -> Preferences
2. In the Preferences dialog's TreeView (left), select General -> Network Connections